# Codename One: log which code is calling another code

Tags: codenameone

*This question is referring to Codename One only.*

*Short story:* I'm debugging a strange bug that occurs only in real devices but not in the Simulator. There is method that is called every second in a particular circumstance, so I suspected a timer. But which timer? To investigate who is calling this method:

1. I enabled `setEnableAsyncStackTraces(true)` (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/better-error-logging.html)
2. I inserted this exception in the method: `throw new IllegalStateException("Who Is Calling me?");`

After that, I discovered which timer is calling my method. However, this way to debug is not always praticable, because it forces me to insert an exception that crashes the app.

Do you have a suggestion? Do you think that a new API like `Log.printAsyncStackTrace()` can be useful in these cases?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
try { 
   throw new RuntimeException("This is the caller");
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
   Log.e(e);
   Log.sendLogAsync();
}
```

It's not as efficient as it should be but a log won't be much more efficient and might be abused by developers. At least this looks bad enough so developers know not to leave it in production.